# Recursively get pivot table data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

This one is quite hard to explain and word, so i apologise if the title doesn't make sense!

Basically at the moment I have a pivot table like this

```
ID | USER_ID | FRIEND_ID
1  |       1 |        2
2  |       5 |        10
3  |       2 |        5
4  |       3 |        9
5  |       5 |        4
```

And I can get all of the friends for a user by having my relationship like this

```
public function user_friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friends', 'user_friend', 'USER_ID', 'FRIEND_ID');
}
```

I want to be able to access all of my friends friends recursively in the cleanest way possible by referencing 1 id.

For example, if i get the user with an id of 1 and call the above `user_friends` method, it would return friend with an id of 2 and that is it.

But friend 2 also has a friend with the id of 5, and id 5 has friends with the id's of 10 and 4, and so on, so i also want to get all of those as-well.

Basically by calling a single user id, I want to get each of the friends that are directly linked to user 1, then recursively get each of their friends, and so on and so forth until I have all of the friends that can be linked to user 1 in some way, shape or form.

Is this possible?

Comment: Beware, you could get stuck in a infinite loop with this structure if not carefull.

Comment: Wouldn't this basically select all of your users in the end? Assuming there are no completely isolated groups.

Comment: Would it be okay to show us your user model? The one where you are defining the relationship

Comment: @DevinGray The `user_friends()` code above is whats defining the relationship in my users model